# Mailer send nil records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am running tasks to scrap a website to get some concert dates.

My tasks are finding/updating the concerts (date and city), and record them in the data base. I can find them in my rails console and also they can be displayed in my index and show views.
BTW it seems it doesn't go through the create method in the ConcertController (I tried with binding.pry)

After the task is run, I want to get an email alert if a new record was found. When I receive the email it's not complete:

**concert_mailer/new_dates.html.erb**

```
<p>The boys are playing at <%= @concert.city %> on <%= @concert.date %></p>
#returns The boys are playing at on 

<p>The boys are playing at <%= @concert.inspect %> </p>

#returns: The boys are playing at <Concert id: 1, date: nil, city: nil, created_at: "2017-12-05 20:32:09", updated_at: "2017-12-05 20:32:09">
```

In rails console I have the record:

```
<Concert id: 1, date: "2017-12-08 00:00:00", city: "ECHANGE CULTUREL CAMEROUN (0)  | au 18 décembre 20...", created_at: "2017-12-05 20:32:09", updated_at: "2017-12-05 20:32:10">
```

**Btw here are my tasks:**

```
 namespace :scrap do
  desc "This get MM concerts"

    url = "http://mountain-men.fr/concerts/"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    data = doc.search('#dateconcert table')
    data = data.css('.jaunec' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) } + doc.css('.jaunef' ).map { |tr| tr.css('td').map(&:text) }

  task :find_concerts  => :environment do

    data.each do |concert|
      c = Concert.create!
      c.date = concert[0]
      c.city = concert[1]
      c.save
    end

  end

  task :update_concerts  => :environment do

    existing_date = Concert.all.map { |c| [c.date, c.city] }

    data.each do |concert|
      c = Concert.create!
      c.date = concert[0]
      c.city = concert[1]
      c.save unless existing_date.include?([concert[0], concert[1]])
    end
      Concert.where(city: nil, date:nil).destroy_all

  end
end
```

**concert.rb**

```
class Concert < ApplicationRecord
   after_create :send_notification

   def send_notification
    ConcertMailer.new_dates(self).deliver_now
   end
end
```

**concert_mailer.rb**

```
class ConcertMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default from: "concert@mountain-men.fr"

  def new_dates(concert)
    @concert = concert

    mail( to:   "email@exemple.com",
         subject:  "The boys are back in town"
        )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your after_create callback to trigger the email is being called before you update your `Concert` object with data. Instead of creating a empty object, try adding values to your fields before you save the `Concert` object.

Something like this:

```
data.each do |concert|
  c = Concert.new
  c.date = concert[0]
  c.city = concert[1]
  c.save
end
```

Or this :

```
data.each do |concert| 
  Concert.create(date: concert[0], city: concert[1]) 
end
```

This way you will have values saved before the `after_create` callback is triggered.